# Error in updating service reference for Restful WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I am new to WCF and have created my first project in WCF using Rest services. I have created 2 methods in the WCF service and the return string is a JSON string and then build the project. I am able to access the WCF service in the web. I have created a Windows Application and added the Service Reference of the Rest WCF project. In the Windows application, I am able to access the 2 methods from WCF service. Then I added another method in the WCF service, build it and then when I select update reference in the Windows application, I am having problem accessing it. Once I update it, in the **app.config**, the client endpoint gets disappears and I am not able to access the service reference in the project. I have no clue as to what the problem could be. Please find my WCF code

My interface code

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IRibbleService
{
   [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string HelloWorld();
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string AddMessageToHistory(Message message);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetMessagesFromHistory(string[] participants, string timestamp);
}
[DataContract]
[Serializable]
public class Message
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DateSent { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string From { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string To { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

My Service.svc

```
public class RibbleService
{
  public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return string.Format("Hello World");
    }

    public string AddMessageToHistory(Message message)
    {
      return "";
    }

    public string GetMessagesFromHistory(string[] participants, string timestamp)
    {
      return "";
    }
 }
```

Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RibbleWCFService.RibbleService" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760" maxBufferSize="10485760">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10485760" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="restBehavior">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

I am wondering if there is a problem in the endpoint that i have declared in web.config file. Can someone please help me in figuring the problem?

Thanks,
Rajagopalan

Comment: Why is your service RibbleService not implementing the Interface? If you navigate to MyService.svc does your service work? Do you get a page?

Comment: I am implementing my interface to RibbleService. forgot to copy the code correctly. When i navigate to MyService.svc wsdl, i am able to see the methods declared. The problem is that in the client side after updating my service, when i reference the service reference in the .cs code, it's not showing eventhough the Service Reference is there in the project.